# set input attribute:name based on radio value jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I'm really struggling with this being fairly new to jQuery, but I sense I am getting close, and would really appreciate some help to make the last bit work please.

The aim is to set the name attribute of #funky in the second form with the value of the radio button selected in the first form (name "dialChoice").

It is working, but only changing the #funky name to the value DL1-BLCK - whichever radio button is clicked.  Can somebody kind tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Thanks in advance

```
<form>
<label>Black </label><input class="dial" type="radio" id="color1" name="dialChoice" value="DL1-BLCK" />
<label>White </label><input class="dial" type="radio" id="color2" name="dialChoice" value="DL1-WHTE" />

<label>Value of Radio Button choice </label>
<input type="text" id="dialSKU" name="dialName" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="/">
<input id="funky" name="" value="1" />
</form>


<script>
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.dial').change(function() {
    $('#dialSKU').val($('.dial').val());  
$('#funky').attr('name', $('[name=dialChoice]').val());
    });
});
})( jQuery );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name=dialChoice]').val()
```

That's a global selector.  It will find both of them.  You only want the selected one.

```
$('[name=dialChoice]:checked').val()
```

OR just reference the dial that was changed, in the handler

```
$('.dial').change(function() {
    $('#dialSKU').val(this.value);  
    $('#funky').attr('name', this.value);
});
```

Comment: Wonderful - thanks!  Both work, but your second suggestion is neater: I'm really grateful ....

Comment: Glad it was helpful, :)

Comment: Taplar, if you email me via the contact on jesterwatch.com, I'd like to send you a thank you present ....

Comment: It's all good man.  I do this just cause I like helping people and a lot of people have helped me in the past so, ya know.  Share the love.